# How to link with ntdll.lib using CMake?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, cmake

I am using `ntdll.lib` functions in my code to set the system timer to a higher resolution.

But when I build my project I get this error:

```
...
.../bin/ld.exe: ... undefined reference to `__imp_NtSetTimerResolution'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
...
```

How do I tell the linker to link with `ntdll.lib` in my CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
if (WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(executable ntdll)
endif()
```

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT hi, I marked it as a solution. I couldn't do it immediately and kinda forgotten afterwards, so thanks for the reminder.